# Oracle Stored Procedure takes much longer from MVC UI than it does in SQL Developer

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, odp.net

So, I'm trying to implement a call to a stored procedure through my ASP.Net MVC web application. Calling the stored procedure isn't the issue though. When I manually run the procedure in SQL Developer, it takes roughly 15 seconds, however, calling it on the backend of my application has wildly different results. Even smaller sets of data can take roughly 20 minutes.

I have tried a handful of permutations on the following two c# examples with no luck; along with trying to set a local variable in the procedure and using that instead of the parameter throughout the script. (It's probably worth noting that I have two other operations in different parts of the code that are more or less mirrors of these examples).

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var connStr = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();

        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":in_val", OracleDbType.Int32, val, ParameterDirection.Input); // val is an int that is passed to the method

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
     }
}
```

And

```
var in_val = new OracleParameter("in_val", OracleDbType.Long, val, ParameterDirection.Input);
context.Database.SqlQuery<object>("BEGIN PROCEDURE_NAME(:in_val); end;", in_val);
```

Here is the stored procedure (edited for space):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_NAME (in_val IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM "SOME_TABLE"
    WHERE  CAST_RUN_ID = in_val;

    INSERT INTO "SOME_TABLE"
     ("col1",
     "col2",
     "col3")
    SELECT distinct
     sot."col1",
     sot."col2",
     sot."col3"
   FROM SOME_OTHER_TABLE  sot
   WHERE sot.col1 = in_val AND sot.col4 IN
    (SELECT col4 FROM (
        SELECT sot1.* 
        FROM SOME_OTHER_TABLE sot1
        WHERE sot1.col3 = 
            (SELECT MAX(sot2.col3) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY col2 DESC NULLS LAST)
            FROM SOME_OTHER_TABLE sot2
            WHERE sot2.col1 = sot1.col1)));
end;
```

The long and short of it is that the procedure groups data and takes a handful of rows from each group. I'm not entirely convinced that the issue lies within the stored procedure seeing as how it's very performant in SQL Developer. I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing since I have two separate methods that do the same thing without this issue.

Edit: I'm seeing the same issue with a different call to a stored procedure that previously ran very fast. So it seems this is isn't an isolated incident.

Comment: That is odd.  I am skeptical that it is a C# issue.  Maybe start an oracle trace on the session and examine the results.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I updated the question, but the issue seemed to appear for other calls to stored procedures. This previously wasn't an issue for them either and seemed to just appear out of nowhere. Due to permission issues, I'm not able to perform any oracle trace though.

Comment: I don't think it should be bound as OracleDbType.Long. That is a extremely large oracle datatype and could be the cause of your problem (maybe it is eating a lot of memory). Try using something else

Comment: I don't know if you ever resolved this, but I have seen the same issue. Somehow the c# call takes forever, like it is blocked or something initially.